# Silex 2 addListener trigger error

Tags: php, silex, dispatcher, event-listener

I'm trying to add an event listener/dispatcher to one of my controller action.
It's goal is to add default data to my entity before persisting it in my database.

Here is what I've got so far.

**app.php**

```
$app['dispatcher']->addListener('my_event_name', function (Event $event) {
    // do something;
});
```

It ends up with the following error :

> ( ! ) InvalidArgumentException: Identifier "dispatcher" does not contain an object definition. in /var/www/site/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php on line 233

Comment: Can you post your whole controller code? From the error I would say that the ```$app``` container does not have the dispatcher identifier configured, which is [weird](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/HttpKernelServiceProvider.php#L76).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread. Looks like it has to do with a precise order in which you call and initialize.

```
$this->before(function () {
    $this['dispatcher']->addListener($eventName, $callback);
});
```

https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler/issues/70#issuecomment-170399805